# Building an activity from button click

Tags: android, json, android-intent

I build a UI based on JSON Objects sent in a method. Each time the method runs, a new row is added to the UI. I need my chartsButtonListener to be able to access the JSONObject `question`.

```
public void buildQuestions(JSONObject question) throws JSONException {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().
    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    questionContainer = (TableLayout) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.questionContainer);

    View questionBox = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, null);
    questionBox.setId(Integer.parseInt(question.getString("id")));
    TextView title = (TextView) questionBox.findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);
    title.setText(question.getString("title"));

    //omitted code for verbosity

    Button chartsButton = (Button) questionBox.findViewById(R.id.chartsButton);

    Button submitButton = (Button) questionBox.findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    chartsButton.setOnClickListener(chartsListener);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(submitListener);

    TableRow tr = (TableRow) questionBox;
    TableLayout.LayoutParams trParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    trParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
    tr.setLayoutParams(trParams);   
    LinearLayout progressRow = (LinearLayout) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.progressRow);
    progressRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    questionContainer.addView(tr);
}

public OnClickListener chartsListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent chart = new Intent();
        chart.setClass(getActivity(), Chart.class);
        Log.v("", v.getParent().getClass().toString());//returns the TableRow
        startActivity(chart);
    }   
};
```

I am familiar with put extra, but it would be best if I could simply pass the question object to the listener directly, so I could then forward it along to the Intent. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use View.setTag(Object) to associate any arbitrary object to a View.

chartsButton.setTag(question);

And in your onClick, you can do:
Question q = (Question) v.getTag();